# Regex get multiline match only

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to match only multiline strings using regex. But the below regex matches both single and multiline. How can I achieve this using regex?

**Regex**

```
('|"|`)[\s\S]*?(\1)
```

**Test string**

```
"not a match"
"need
to
match"
```

https://regex101.com/r/DXahXG/1

Comment: Not sure if there's a way to get rid of the repetition but `"[^"]+\n[^"]*"|'[^']+\n[^']*'|\`[^\`]+\n[^\`]*\`` should work fine. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/S2ilct/1).

Comment: I'd suggest to filter out matches not containing `\n` after the results you get with your current regex.. you can also use ``(['"`])`` instead of ``('|"|`)`` and `.` instead of `[\s\S]` if `s` flag is supported

Answer (score 2):

Your input string contains *three* potential sub substrings between double quotes:

- `"not a match"`
- `"\n"`
- `"need\nto\nmatch"`

That means, you can hardly rely on lookarounds, as there is a chance the regex engine will pick up the ending `"` of a failed pair as the leading `"` of the next double quote pair. The `` (['"`])(?:(?!\1).)*\n[\s\S]*?\1 `` regex is an [illustration](https://regex101.com/r/ixPwhe/1) of this problem.

In this regard, it is much safer to just use your regex and then filter out all those matches that contain a newline char:

```js
const text = '"not a match"\n"need\nto\nmatch"';
const rx = /(['"`]).*?\1/gs;
console.log( text.match(rx).filter(x => x.includes('\n')) )
```

Answer (score 0):

A multiline string is a string that contains at least one newline. So you could write

```
('|"|`)[\s\S]*?\n[\s\S]*(\1)
```

But that would match your whole example, since `[\s\S]*` also matches the string delimiter.

You might want to try

```
'[^']*?\n[^']*?'|"[^']*?\n[^']*?"|`[^']*?\n[^']*?`
```

But that one does not match escaped quotation marks.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/cAIXLy/1) is too complex?

```
('|"|`)(?:(?:(?!\1).)+?\n)+(?:(?!\1).)+\1
```

Break down:

```
                ┌─ matches 1 or more of this
                │                ┌─ followed by one or more
                │                │  non-quote-like characters
                │                │      ┌─ matches closing
       ┌────────┴─────────┐┌─────┴────┐┌┤  quote-like characters
('|"|`)(?:(?:(?!\1).)+?\n)+(?:(?!\1).)+\1
└──┬──┘   │  │    ││     │
   └────────────────────────────── matches opening quote-like character
          │  │    ││     │         and captures it in group 1
          │  │    ││     │
          │  └──┬─┘└─────│──────── matches any character
          │     └────────│──────── which is not an quote-like character
          └────┬─────────┘
               └──────── and matches 1 or more of them, as few as possible
                         followed by line break
```